# How to execute multiple commands to a command line program one by one using python?

Tags: python, cmd, python-os

How to execute multiple commands to a command line program(.exe) one by one using python. I need to send commands and need to read the reply on the command line for each command. All in one session since login and settings has to be done.

I tried the below code(python 3.6) but it's not working

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
process = Popen( "cmd.exe", shell=False, universal_newlines=True,
                  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE ) 



cmd= "\"C:\temp\demo.exe\"\n"
out, err = process.communicate(cmd)

print(out)

out, err = process.communicate( 'login\n' )

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can execute multiple commands

```
import subprocess

command_list=["C:\\temp\\demo.exe","echo hello"]

for command in command_list:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    print("{} : {}".format(command,out.decode()))
```

Because `shell=True` is not the need for `cmd.exe`

Comment: I replaced command_list  with ["\"C:\temp\demo.exe\"", "login"]. It's getting stuck at out, err = proc.communicate()